# Assign a Seq(Seq) into arrays

Tags: raku

What is it the correct syntax to assign a Seq(Seq) into multiple typed arrays without assign the Seq to an scalar first? Has the Seq to be flattened somehow? This fails:

```
class A { has Int $.r }

my A (@ra1, @ra2);

#create two arrays with 5 random numbers below a certain limit

#Fails: Type check failed in assignment to @ra1; expected A but got Seq($((A.new(r => 3), A.n...)
(@ra1, @ra2) =
   <10 20>.map( -> $up_limit {
        (^5).map({A.new( r => (^$up_limit).pick ) })
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not entirely sure if it's by design, but what seems to happen is that both of your sequences are getting stored into `@ra1`, while `@ra2` remains empty. This violates the type constraint.

What does work is

```
@ra1, @ra2 Z= <10 20>.map(...);
```

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** Binding is faster than assignment, so perhaps this is the best practice solution to your problem:

```
:(@ra1, @ra2) := <10 20>.map(...);
```

While uglier than the solution in the accepted answer, this is algorithmically faster because binding is `O(1)` in contrast to assignment's `O(N)` in the length of the list(s) being bound.

## Assigning / copying

Simplifying, your non-working code is:

```
(@listvar1, @listvar2) = list1, list2;
```

In Raku infix `=` means assignment / copying from the right of the `=` *into* one or more of the [container](https://docs.raku.org/language/containers) variables on the left of the `=`.

If a variable on the left is bound to a [`Scalar` container](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar), then it will assign one of the values on the right. Then the assignment process starts over with the next container variable on the left and the next value on the right.

If a variable on the left is bound to an [`Array` container](https://docs.raku.org/type/Array), then it uses up all remaining values on the right. So your *first* array variable receives both `list1` and `list2`. This is not what you want.

---

Simplifying, here's Christoph's answer:

```
@listvar1, @listvar2 Z= list1, list2;
```

Putting the `=` aside for a moment, `Z` is an infix version of [the `zip` routine](https://docs.raku.org/routine/zip). It's like ([a physical zip](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/26/10/15/zip-2345684_960_720.jpg) pairing up consecutive arguments on its left and right. When used with an operator it applies that operator to the pair. So you can read the above `Z=` as:

```
@listvar1 = list1;
@listvar2 = list2;
```

Job done?

---

Assignment *into* `Array` containers entails:

- *Individually copying* as many individual items as there are in each list *into* the containers. (In the code in your example `list1` and `list2` contain 5 elements each, so there would be 10 copying operations in total.)
- Forcing the containers to resize as necessary to accommodate the items.
- Doubling up the memory used by the items (the original list elements and the duplicates copied into the `Array` elements).
- Checking that the type of each item matches the element type constraint.

Assignment is in general much slower and more memory intensive than binding...

## Binding

```
:(@listvar1, @listvar2) := list1, list2;
```

The `:=` operator [*binds*](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_:=) whatever's on its left to the arguments on its right.

If there's a single variable on the left then things are especially simple. After binding, the variable now refers precisely to what's on the right. (This is especially simple and fast -- a quick type check and it's done.)

But that's not so in our case.

Binding also accepts a standalone signature literal on its left. The `:(...)` in my answer is a standalone [`Signature`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature) literal.

(Signatures are typically attached to a routine without the colon prefix. For example, in `sub foo (@var1, @var2) {}` the `(@var1, @var2)` part is a signature attached to the routine `foo`. But as you can see, one can write a signature separately and let Raku know it's a signature by prefixing a pair of parens with a colon. A key difference is that any variables listed in the signature must have already been declared.)

When there's a signature literal on the left then binding happens according to the same logic as binding arguments in routine calls to a receiving routine's signature.

So the net result is that the variables get the values they'd have inside this sub:

```
sub foo (@listvar1, @listvar2) { }
foo list1, list2;
```

which is to say the effect is the same as:

```
@listvar1 := list1;
@listvar2 := list2;
```

Again, as with Christoph's answer, job done.

But this way we'll have avoided assignment overhead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I wonder what is the reason for `Cannot use bind operator with this left-hand side`?  Another thing: I tried `my (@a, @b) := [1], [2, 3]` and it works, but I was not able to make this approach to work with the OP's `map`. For example: `(@ra1, @ra2) := [<10 20>.map( -> $up_limit {[ (^5).map({A.new( r => (^$up_limit).pick ) })]` --> `Cannot use bind ...`

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland :) ["One-pass parsing is darn near mandatory"](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/) ... ["for an extensible, braided language"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/a4z68q/what_principles_have_you_adopted_for_your/ebl8vsr/). Once the parser reaches and parses the `:=` it's committed itself to interpreting the thing on the left as a `List`. The `(@a, @b)` in `my (@a, @b)` is a `Signature`, very similar to a `:(@ra1, @ra2)` signature literal, as explained in my answer, albeit without the preceding colon. In contrast `(@ra1, @ra2)` is a `List`.

Comment: Hi @raiph. Thanks for coming back to this comment again. After testing a little bit more, the question I have can be reduced to:  `my A (@a, @b); (@a, @b) := [A.new(r =>1)], [A.new(r => 2)];` --> does not work. But if I do not predeclare `@a` and `@b`:  `my A (@a, @b) := [A.new(r =>1)], [A.new(r => 2)];` it works! What am I missing here?

Comment: The `my` lets the parser know you're declaring something. The `A` is plausibly a type so the parser allows for that and that works out. Next, it sees a left paren, so it thinks "ah, must be a list of identifiers being declared". Sure enough, when it gets to the right paren that pans out so it decides "yeah", that's a `my A (...)` sort of signature thing. But when you instead write code that starts with a left paren without the preceding `my` the parser thinks "we've got an *expression* here". By the end paren it's parsed a `List`. And it's too late to change that when it hits the `:=`.

Comment: It's likely we *could* make it DWIM, making it so that if `:=` discovers it's got a list on its left it converts it to a signature, or perhaps come up with yet another way to bind that's specially for binding to a list, but for now the language just complains, essentially saying "stick a colon on the front if you want binding like it is when you call a routine". Curiously a `my (...)` style signature doesn't behave quite the same as a `:(...)` style signature (which isn't quite the same as a `sub foo (...)` style signature). I really don't think we want another one...